# Does the melee attack in Retributive Strike require an action?

Tags: combat, actions, pathfinder-2e

The text for Retributive Stike says:

> You protect your ally and strike your foe. The ally gains resistance
> to all damage against the triggering damage equal to 2 + your level.
> If the foe is within reach, make a melee Strike against it.

Does that mean that I have to spend one of my three actions for this melee strike or is it an extra strike?

And if I already made multiple attacks in this round do I get a Multiple Attack Penalty on this attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It costs your Reaction

[Paladins](https://2e.aonprd.com/Causes.aspx?ID=1) get the Champion Reaction Retributive Strike. [Reactions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=62) are a type of Action, but they do not cost your normal Action points, and they don't have to be used on your turn (although you only get 1 per round, plus any bonus Reactions from Feats, which "refresh" at the start of your turn when you gain Actions). More rules on using Reactions are found in the [Encounter Mode rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=442) and to a lesser extent under the [Actions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=387) section (see Actions with Triggers).

You do not take your [Multiple Attack Penalty](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=322) on Retributive Strike attacks; MAP does not apply to any Reaction unless stated otherwise (such as with [Readied](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=82) Strikes)

> The multiple attack penalty applies only during your turn, so you don’t have to keep track of it if you can perform an Attack of Opportunity or a similar reaction that lets you make a Strike on someone else’s turn.

Comment: Please note that, if you triggered the reaction on your turn, you would actually apply your current MAP.

Comment: Technically that might be correct for this Reaction; however, I consider it clear that the intent (see [Attack of Opportunity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=8)'s reminder and the vagueness of the quoted rule in this answer) is MAP should never apply to Strikes as part of Reactions. It's worth asking your GM, at any rate.